# DAX - Summary table for Planned and Executed production

Tags: join, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a problem witn joining two tables (tbPlan and tbExecuted).
The tbPlan is like this

| Date | SKU | Shift | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 1 | 10 |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 2 | 5 |
| 1/1/2023 | B | 1 | 10 |

and the tbExecuted is like:

| Date | SKU | Shift | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 1 | 10 |
| 2/1/2023 | A | 1 | 5 |
| 1/1/2023 | B | 1 | 5 |
| 1/1/2023 | B | 2 | 5 |

The join table must have all the information for planning and executed like this:

| Date | SKU | Shift | Plan | Executed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 1/1/2023 | A | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 2/1/2023 | A | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 1/1/2023 | B | 1 | 10 | 5 |
| 1/1/2023 | B | 2 | 0 | 5 |

I tried to use this DAX code (real names of tables and columns)

```
FACT-TabelaAderencia =        
VAR A = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        summProducao
       ;"Data"; summProducao[DataProducao]+0
       ;"SKU"; Upper(summProducao[SKU])
       ;"Turno"; summProducao[Turno]*1
       ;"Produzido"; summProducao[Cargas Produzidas]
    )       
VAR B = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        summPlanejamento
        ;"Data"; summPlanejamento[DataProgramada1]+0
        ;"SKU"; UPPER(summPlanejamento[SKU])
        ;"Turno"; summPlanejamento[Turno]*1
        ;"Planejado"; summPlanejamento[Planejadas] 
    )
VAR Result = NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(A; B)  
Return Result
```

The NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN show only the 0s on the first argument of the function (if I put tbPlan, none row with 0 executed is shown). And vice-versa.
The NATURALINNERJOIN kills both rows with 0 in tbPlan or tbExecuted.

Is there a way to achieve this goal of having a summary of planning and executed in one summary table?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN` is always a left join. So, you have left table and get it with some appended values.
You can't reach the goal with a join, but you can use some other technics. I used `UNION()` and `GROUPBY()`, but there are still other ways to get the same output.

```
VAR planFact =
    UNION(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            plan
           ,"Data", plan[Date]+0
           ,"SKU", UPPER(plan[SKU])
           ,"Turno", plan[Shift]*1
           ,"Produzido",VALUE("0")
          ,"Planejado", plan[pQty]
        ) 
       ,
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            'fact'
            ,"Data", 'fact'[Date]+0
            ,"SKU", UPPER('fact'[SKU])
            ,"Turno", 'fact'[Shift]*1     
            ,"Produzido", 'fact'[fQty]
            ,"Planejado",VALUE("0")
        )
  )
RETURN
    GROUPBY(
        planFact                   
        ,[Data]
        ,[SKU]
        ,[Turno]
        ,"Planejado",SUMX(CURRENTGROUP (),[Planejado])      
        ,"Produzido",SUMX(CURRENTGROUP (),[Produzido])
    )
```

[image]

Comment: You are welcome ). Glad to know was useful )

Answer (score 1):

Merging tables is **really** not something you should be doing using DAX. However, you can do this in Power Query with a full join and some null-coalesing operators. Here is some (really ugly)  code:

`tbPlan`:

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMtQ31DcyMDJW0lFyBGJDEDZQitXBkDECYlN0CSckLbEA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, SKU = _t, Shift = _t, Qty = _t]),
  #"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Date", type date}, {"SKU", type text}, {"Shift", Int64.Type}, {"Qty", Int64.Type}})
in
  #"Changed column type"
```

`tbExecuted`:

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMtQ31DcyMDJW0lFyBGJDEDZQitWJVjLClDEFSyBpccInYQSRiAUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, SKU = _t, Shift = _t, Qty = _t]),
  #"Changed column type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Date", type date}, {"SKU", type text}, {"Shift", Int64.Type}, {"Qty", Int64.Type}})
in
  #"Changed column type"
```

And the merged table code:

```
let
  Source = Table.NestedJoin(tbPlan, {"Date", "SKU", "Shift"}, tbExecuted, {"Date", "SKU", "Shift"}, "tbExecuted", JoinKind.FullOuter),
  #"Expanded tbExecuted" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "tbExecuted", {"Date", "SKU", "Shift", "Qty"}, {"Date.1", "SKU.1", "Shift.1", "Qty.1"}),
  #"Added custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded tbExecuted", "DateTemp", each [Date] ?? [Date.1]),
  #"Added custom 1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added custom", "SKUTemp", each [SKU] ?? [SKU.1]),
  #"Added custom 2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added custom 1", "ShiftTemp", each [Shift] ?? [Shift.1]),
  #"Added custom 3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added custom 2", "Qty Plan", each [Qty] ?? 0),
  #"Added custom 4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added custom 3", "Qty Executed", each [Qty.1] ?? 0),
  #"Removed other columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added custom 4", {"DateTemp", "SKUTemp", "ShiftTemp", "Qty Plan", "Qty Executed"}),
  #"Renamed columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed other columns", {{"DateTemp", "Date"}, {"SKUTemp", "SKU"}, {"ShiftTemp", "Shift"}})
in
  #"Renamed columns"
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Marcus for the fast response. 
In fact, both tbPlan and tbExecuted are virtual tables that has some treatments on the original tables. 
Anyway, I'm thankful for your help.